# access docmd.outputto of a report doesn't cause report_load or other events to fire

Tags: ms-access

Please do not close my question again - I've included specific behavior needed and code example of what causes the problem

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub testreportoutputto()
'DoCmd.OpenReport "report1", acViewPreview
'Stop
' this technique does not fire the report_load event

DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "report1", acFormatPDF, "c:\temp\report.pdf", True

End Sub
```

Access 2016 on Premises I've looked at the other similar postings but none quite fit my circumstances.

I issue a docmd.openreport ... and it works fine. This report has a few on events, such as Report_load, Header_format, etc to dynamcially change the header page, etc.

However, when I do a docmd.outputto acreport, reportname, ... to send it directly to a PDF, the on events do not fire. How do I get VBA control during the formatting process when it writes it directly to disk. I guess I could bring up the report in print preview and do some kind of sendkeys to save the report but seems a bit awkward to me.

The desired behavior is for the Report_load procedure to fire when the docmd.output command is issued

example code `docmd.output to acreport, "report name", afformatpdf, "c:\filelocation"`

Comment: I did a test and Format events do fire. You answered your own question. If you want Load event to fire then open report in PrintPreview.

Comment: Please read and apply https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Code provided does not error, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. There is no error. There is no code attempt to resolve your issue therefore question is candidate to close. Exactly what changes are desired on the header?

Comment: It does NOT fire when using docmd.outputto.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that only report load doesn't fire on outputto -
So I'm able to work around that -
thanks